# Ubuntu 20.04 Sees my LiDE30 scanner, but cannot use it

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner, canon

When I run `lsusb` I can see my scanner

`enter code here`Bus 001 Device 009: ID 04a9:220e Canon, Inc. CanoScan N1240U/LiDE 30

However, when I open "Document Scanner", it gives me the message "No scanners detected".

I am using `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`.

What do I need to do to make it detect the scanner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a driver conflict for many Canon scanners in Ubuntu 20.04, where  `ippusbxd` tries to claim the device, locking it from use. If you disconnect and plug the scanner back into your machine then run `dmesg -w`, you'll likely see this message somewhere in the output:

```
usb 1-11: usbfs: process 5756 (ippusbxd) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

The most common solution is to unplug the scanner, then remove the `ippusbxd` driver completely:

```
sudo apt remove ippusbxd
```

Once this is done, reconnect the scanner. It should be visible *and usable* in any document scanning application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It wasn't exactly what I needed, but running `dmesg -w` told me that the port I was using (via my keyboard) was not powerful enough. So I switched it to my desktop's port and it worked.